# How to pass data from servlet to jsp so it is accessible to an appropriate user?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I'm quite new to Jsp and Servlets and struggling to understands how does request attribute differs from session. I have created a web app with login authorisation, and I want all the data that belongs to a session user be only accessible to him. I have user `request.setAttribute()` to pass the objects, but I'm afraid that other users might have access to it as well. Maybe, be someone could explain this in more depth...

Comment: Suppose you have custom servlet where you define your login logic. Multiple thread could access same login `instance` at same time. Java Thread and servlet docs could give you lucid idea.

Comment: if you're creating stateful sessions on the server with lots of state ... you may be doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set logged user data in session objects. You can create separate pojo class to set and get the object values.
Based on the logged user you can transitive the session data.